# CakePHP Paypal IPN Plugin email not working

Tags: php, cakephp, php-5.5, cakephp-2.5

I'm using [this](https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Paypal-IPN-Plugin) plugin in a CakePHP Application. Everything seems to work except sending emails.

I have the following code in AppController.php

```
function afterPaypalNotification($txnId)
{
    //Here is where you can implement code to apply the transaction to your app.
    //for example, you could now mark an order as paid, a subscription, or give the user premium access.
    //retrieve the transaction using the txnId passed and apply whatever logic your site needs.

    $transaction = ClassRegistry::init('PaypalIpn.InstantPaymentNotification')->findById($txnId);
    $this->log($transaction['InstantPaymentNotification']['id'], 'paypal');

    //Tip: be sure to check the payment_status is complete because failure
    //     are also saved to your database for review.

    if ($transaction['InstantPaymentNotification']['payment_status'] == 'Completed') 
    {
        //Yay!  We have monies!
        ClassRegistry::init('PaypalIpn.InstantPaymentNotification')->email(array(
            'id' => $txnId,
            'subject' => 'Thanks!',
            'message' => 'Thank you for the transaction!'
        ));
    }
    else
    {
        //Oh no, better look at this transaction to determine what to do; like email a decline letter.
        ClassRegistry::init('PaypalIpn.InstantPaymentNotification')->email(array(
            'id' => $txnId,
            'subject' => 'Failed!',
            'message' => 'Please review your transaction'
        ));
    }
}
```

But the data returned from Paypal is saved in the instant_payment_notifications table but for some reason the emails are not sent. Has anybody tried this plugin before and did the email fonctionality work?

Do I need to enable email.php in app/Config for the emails to work? I read somewhere on Cake's website that I don't need that file for emails to work, so I guess that's not where the problem is.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In CakePhp 2.5 you should use [CakeEmail](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html)

Create the file /app/Config/email.php with the class EmailConfig. The /app/Config/email.php.default has an example of this file.

Add following line in /app/Controller/AppController.php before class declaration

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
```

In afterPaypalNotification function replace

```
ClassRegistry::init('PaypalIpn.InstantPaymentNotification')->email(array(
    'id' => $txnId,
    'subject' => 'Thanks!',
    'message' => 'Thank you for the transaction!'
));
```

with (fast e-mail, no style)

```
CakeEmail::deliver('customer@example.com', 'Thanks!', 'Thank you for the transaction!', array('from' => 'you@example.com'));
```

or

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->template('email_template', 'email_layout')
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->to('customer@example.com')
    ->from('you@domain.com')
    ->viewVars(array('id' => $txnId))
    ->send();
```

Email template goes to /app/View/Emails/html/email_template.ctp

Email layouts goes to /app/View/Layouts/Emails/html/email_layout.ctp